# sql server alter permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Experts

I am trying to set up permission for our IT team. All our IT staffs are member of I.T group. With  the database in question  the IT staffs  groups are member of db_reader, db_reader and can execute all SP/Fun. one particular user I want to give the permission to modify the objects.

```
CREATE USER [S\Al] FOR LOGIN [S\Al] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

added him to db_ddlAmin role

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ddladmin', N'S\Al'
```

all the objects in our db belongs to DBO schema..so i have give alter permission on dbo schema to the user

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [S\Al]
```

But when this user tries to modify an sp or drop a table he gets

```
Cannot alter the procedure 'XX', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Cannot drop table 'XX', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

This user can create a new table, but if he tries to drop the newly  created table he get the permission error..

This user is member of 4 other group where the group  is a member of either db_owner or db_ddladmin role,

What am I doing wrong, how can i resolve this..

Thanks

VT

Comment: Do any of the groups that they're a member of have any explicit `DENY`s? `DENY` always trumps `GRANT`.

Answer (score 0):

Members of the `db_ddladmin` role should be able to modify stored procedures.

Make sure you've added the user to the role in the correct database:

```
use YourDatabase;
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ddladmin', N'S\Al'
```

Without an explicit `use`, you might have made him a member of the `master` database's `db_dlladmin` role!